# Why are my search results in Google missing the descriptions?

Tags: google-search

I have been dealing with this problem for 2 days now, when I search for something the Google search results are showing, but the descriptions or snippets that normally appear below are missing, so I only get the title links without any further information.

At first, I thought that this was malware, but I checked with an anti-virus and everything was normal. Then I noticed that this is a problem in any device (phone, tablet, or computer) I use that has this specific google account.

When I change accounts the search results are normal, so I think this is something related to my account, though I have been unable to find a fix on the internet or with google help.

I leave an image for everyone to see the problem:

[image]

I use Google Chrome version 100.0.4896.127. My account is a consumer/free account. The problem only appears in the usual search, in incognito mode, the problem disappears. Also, I disabled all the extensions and the problem persisted, but when I change the account (to another consumer account) the problem does not appear. The problem only shows when I search with my account.

Answer (score 2):

This was a [Google Community answer](https://support.google.com/websearch/thread/174809420/google-image-preview-not-working-correctly-when-signed-in?hl=en) I sent to a friend that had the same issue during the same time. I hope this can help other people.

> If Google Search looks different only when signed in to a particular Google account, you're probably seeing a Google Live Experiment (or perhaps an experiment gone wrong!).
>
> Google constantly targets random accounts with experimental variations to the Search and Image Search interfaces. Sometimes the differences are barely noticeable. Other variations are much more obvious.
>
> Please refer to this FAQ thread for more information:
> [FAQ] [My Google Search looks different: Google Live Experiments](https://support.google.com/websearch/thread/110115253)
>
> As this is a user-to-user community, there's nothing we can do about this. Please send your feedback direct to Google using the "Send Feedback" link at the bottom of the results page.

In short they told me that the problem that I have happens when Google experiments with certain accounts, and eventually the problem should solve itself. That is what exactly happened to me, for a time I had this problem and then it disappeared without doing anything. It has happened to me twice.

Answer (score -2):

You can reset the Google settings by going to **Settings > Reset and clean up > Restore settings to original defaults > Reset Settings**.